# Signing BlackBerry application

Tags: blackberry, signing

Hi all I'm new in Blackberry development I wanted to know is it necessary to sign all application after development??
If yes then How to sign the application??

Please Help me

Thank you

Abhishek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you do not use signed api (signed api classes are marked in api documentation) it is not necessary, but if you use it, you have to sign the application to launch it on an actual device.

Signing keys can be obtained [from Research In Motion company's web-site](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp).